# Python Factory method and Abstract classes

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, abstract-class, factory

I just saw this code example on a website:

```
class Shape(object):
    # Create based on class name:
    def factory(type):
        #return eval(type + "()")
        if type == "Circle": return Circle()
        if type == "Square": return Square()
        assert 0, "Bad shape creation: " + type
    factory = staticmethod(factory)

class Circle(Shape):
    def draw(self): print("Circle.draw")
    def erase(self): print("Circle.erase")

class Square(Shape):
    def draw(self): print("Square.draw")
    def erase(self): print("Square.erase")
```

I am confused. Wouldn't Square and Circle inherit the method factory because they are inheriting from Shape? 
If so, I don't understand the logic behind it as the factory should be only in the shape.

Comment: Yes, you could do `Square.factory('Circle')`!

Comment: That means that this is probably not the way to go when using a factory method?

Comment: Yeah this doesn't really seem to make any sense, I have no idea why the `Shape` class even exists in this example, `factory()` could just be a standalone function